# use 10.04 Desktop on 12.04 or 13.04

Tags: 10.04

How can I use the GOOD desktop (Pull downs at top, screen switch lower right, lower info ribbon) from 10.04 on 12.04 or 13.04??? The Jitter strip on the left is terrable!!!
any info ro nane of desktop change info might help. since I am still using 10.04 to avoid that Jitter stripdesktop, and it's ending.
THANK YOU  for any help AVAILABLE.
Art

Answer (score 3):

The package you need is called "gnome-session-fallback". Either you install it with the software center or you install it using the shell.
For the first you have to invoke the ubuntu software center from the left sidebar or from the dash and type "gnome session fallback" in the search. Then simply install it.

If you want to use the shell type

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

in your favourite terminal application.

After that you must reboot your system. Maybe a logout is enough. Over the password prompt is a little sign with the Ubuntu logo. If you click on it, you can choose the desktop environment for the next session. Then select "GNOME Fallback" and log in.

Have fun!